# GNOME system-monitor status bar app disappears after standby

Tags: gnome-shell, system-monitor

On Ubuntu 18.04.  When I boot up and log in, the GNOME system-monitor shows up in my status bar exactly like it should, but as soon as the system goes into stand-by and then I wake it up, system-monitor is gone and doesn't return until I reboot.

[image: this thing]

Is there a way I can get this to not happen, or is there an alternative tray app that provides the same functionality but works better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a default feature and it seems it is being provided by some [GNOME Shell  extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions) (you can find out by running `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`). As per GNOME's security policy all the extensions get disabled at lockscreen/suspend and then get reloaded after the user logs back in. It seems in your case somehow the extension is not getting reloaded.

When you face the issue, restart GNOME Shell by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (note: this does *not* work in a Wayland session). This should bring it back.

Comment: That did it.  Certainly not ideal, but I can live with it.